# Persisting data with interactable listview items and the provider pattern

Tags: flutter, dart

This problem can be reframed in terms of a ToDo list with a progress for each item.

I have a list of goals, where each goal has a text and progress

```
class Goal {
    int progress;
    String goalText;
}
```

To display them they are wrapped in ChangeNotifier state objects

```
class GoalListState with ChangeNotifier {
    List<Goal> goals;
}
```

and

```
class GoalState with ChangeNotifier {
    Goal goal;

    GoalState(this.goal)
}
```

Which I then use in a ListView, where each item in the ListView has a progress slider to update the goal progress.

I am now uncertain how to handle persisting data.

The way that I am currently doing it is to wrap the model properties and persist the data when those are updated. This seems very messy:

```
class GoalState with ChangeNotifier {
   set progress(int progress) {
       _goal.progress = progress;
       database.updateGoal(_goal);
       notifyListeners();
   }

   int get progress => _goal.progress;
   Goal _goal;

   GoalState(this._goal);
}
```

What would be a good pattern for this issue?